# When can it happen that you take a pull and you see automatically some changes in the git status?

Tags: git, macos, bitbucket, git-commit, git-pull

*emphasized text*

**MAC OS**

[image]

After taking pull in develop branch, seeing two files removed automatically. any one know when can this happen?

I took a pull in develop branch, and instead of seeing a clean deck, i.e. no changes, I am seeing two files removed.

N.B. These two files were not removed by me, neither they were removed before taking pull.
Before taking pull, there were no uncommitted changes in the repo.

When can it happen that you take a pull and you see automatically some changes in the git status?

Comment: Those files were very likely to have been removed by another commit.

Comment: then why i am seeing those as uncommitted changes?

Comment: That's not the merge doing that then. Do you have a git hook running? Or some other software which is removing the files?

Comment: checking if there is any, but do you mean, it that script removed after taking a pull?

Comment: yes, check whether a script is removing those files after pulling

Comment: yes this files are replaced by scripts, but they do not run after taking a pull. They have to be manually run. Neither did I run that script anytime soon.

Comment: Then something else did it. Git will not delete files an leave them unstaged/uncommitted like that. Unless perhaps you're in the middle of a merge conflict?

Comment: there are known issues when git deals with a case insensitive file system (such as MacOS). In the path to your file : what is the part which is relative to your repo's root ? from a shell, what does `ls shells/iosPreprodJob.sh` output ?

Comment: There was no merge conflict involved here, I am also investigating what could have happened

Comment: `ls dma/shells/iosPreprodJob.sh` returns nothing because actually the file is not there

Comment: what about the paths registered in the current commit ? `git ls-tree -r --name-only HEAD | grep -i shells/`